# How to get Evernote notebooks list using Rest api? without using Evernote SDK

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, rest, evernote

I am developing an IOS app. I need to get Evernote note books using rest api. I don't want to use Evernote SDK. Is there any rest api available? 
I succeeded to get oAuth Access token without using SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evernote does not have a publicly available REST API.  Evernote's iOS SDK has been rewritten recently, is very easy to use and is available here: https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-ios

Evernote uses a binary protocol based on Apache Thrift to communicate with its clients including 3rd party clients such as your application, not HTTP.  OAuth is a HTTP based protocol and is independent from Evernote's client-server binary protocol communication.